# readlines() function does not behave the same way as read() in a single line text

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file.txt
        No device found
**************************
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        if "No device found" in f.readlines():
            print('The requested wwn is not found on Brocade')
    
    output:
    Process finished with exit code 0
    
    
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        if "No device found" in f.read():
            print('The requested wwn is not found on Brocade')
    
    output:
    The requested wwn is not found on Brocade
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

read lines would read on line at a time, is that right? IF yes why doesnt it read the only line present in the file?

Could someone explain what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using readlines(), wich read all the lines and return a list of lines.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        if "No device found" in f.readline():
            print('The requested wwn is not found on Brocade')
```

This should work as intended

Comment: Thanks! I dint notice there is readline() as well.. BUT now why does readlines() not work?Even the readlines() read the entire file right?

Comment: or is it that readlines() should be iterated using for line in readlines() ?

Comment: @redpy As i said, readlines return a list, so the first line is at index 0, readlines()[0] would give you the first line. If you have only one line, it will return something like ["content of line 1"], and ["line 1", "line 2", "line 3"] if you have more line. readline() only read the next line, so in your app, it only read the first line (this will end with \n tho). It depends on your needs

Comment: @redpy Yes, exactly, you can iterate readlines, but you also can do `for line in file`, the good part of readlines is that you can stores it in memory, and close your file, this can take a lot of space with a big file tho.

Answer (score 2):

First let's clarify data types:

- `readlines()` returns a **list** of strings (all lines in the file)
- `read()` reads the whole file contents and returns a single **string**
- `readline()` also returns a single **string** of just the current line

The key difference in your use case is how pythons `in` keyword operates with respect to a string versus a list:

- For a string it is checking if the string you specify is a substring.
- For a list it is checking if the string you specify is an exact match of one of the list elements.

The `"No device found"` string you're looking for is not an exact match in the list, it's a substring of one of the strings in the list (based on your input file as listed that string would be `"        No device found"`).